# Opening DB connection for each method in class

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have written a controller class which contain many methods performing some database transactions. For each method object of DBConnect class is created. I want to know which of the following way is more efficient.

(1) opening connection for each method (as in attached code)

(2) opening a single connection for the class and using it in all the methods of that class
my code is:

```
public class HotelController
{
    Connection conn;
    ResultSet rs;
    PreparedStatement preparedstatement;

    public void addNewHotel( Hotel hotel ) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            conn = DBConnect.getInstance().getConnect();
            String sql = "insert into hotel" + " (hotelName,city) values (?,?)";
            preparedstatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
            preparedstatement.setString( 1, hotel.getName() );
            preparedstatement.setString( 2, hotel.getCity() );

            boolean flag = preparedstatement.execute();
            if ( flag )
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Hotel Details Added Successfully." );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getHotelID( String name ) throws Exception
    {
        int id = 1;
        try
        {
            conn = DBConnect.getInstance().getConnect();
            String sql = "select hotelID from hotel where hotelName = ?";
            preparedstatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
            preparedstatement.setString( 1, name );
            rs = preparedstatement.executeQuery();

            while ( rs.next() )
            {
                id = rs.getInt( 1 );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return id;
    }

    public void loadHotels( JComboBox cbox ) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            conn = DBConnect.getInstance().getConnect();
            String sql = "select hotelName from hotel";
            preparedstatement = conn.prepareStatement( sql );
            rs = preparedstatement.executeQuery();

            while ( rs.next() )
            {
                cbox.addItem( rs.getString( "hotelName" ) );
            }
        }
        catch ( SQLException ex )
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How about a third option of using a dbcp?

Comment: + don't put too much logic in your controllers, that's not a good idea

Comment: The third one: use a connection pool

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Connection Pool**, Because Opening/Closing database connections is an expensive process and hence connection pools improve the performance of execution of commands on a database for which we maintain connection objects in the pool. It facilitates reuse of the same connection object to serve a number of client requests. Every time a client request is received, the pool is searched for an available connection object and it's highly likely that it gets a free connection object. Otherwise, either the incoming requests are queued or a new connection object is created and added to the pool.Since most of the requests are served using existing connection objects only so the connection pooling approach brings down the average time required for the users to wait for establishing the connection to the database.